# Create design area for design Shirt

Tags: html

I want to create design area like this. All design images must be in here
I have no idea to do it. Anyone can help me
Thanks!
[image: this is example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a Image Wrapper with overflow hidden. Of course you can also use a background image and play with background-size. Here is a Code Example for the first Solution: http://codepen.io/webdesignberlin/pen/BoMGyw

HTML:

```
<div class="shirt">
  <figure class="shirt__area">
    <img src="http://letscode.ghost.io/content/images/2015/09/stackoverflow.png" alt="Stackoverflow Logo" class="shirt__image">
  </figure>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.shirt {
  width: 419px;
  height: 437px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Aodf.png') 0 0 no-repeat;

  &__area {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &__image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.